# eclipse plugin - treat non java extension file like a java file

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

We are developing an eclipse plugin and we have an extension like say, ".xyz" but it actually
contains java code. JavaCore.createCompilationUnitFrom() accepts only files with extension ".java". JavaCore has JAVA_SOURCE_CONTENT_TYPE which returns the extensions that it treats as
Java source files.

My questions is How do I add ".xyz" to this list ? I want JavaCore to treat files of ".xyz" extension as java source files.

Any pointers would be very helpful.

Comment: do you just want the files to be opened in the Java editor, or are you looking to process the compilation unit?

Comment: preferably both. But compilation is of higher prio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [bug 71460](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=71460) has introduced support for different extension for java-like sources in eclipse3.1.
The [bug 121715](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=121715) mentions for eclipse3.2, (for supporting `.aj` files as containing Java source):

```
<content-type id="ajSource" name="AspectJ Source File" 
              base-type="org.eclipse.jdt.core.javaSource"
              file-extensions="aj"/>
```

Comment: @Rich: thank you Sir. You should see the other really nasty hack I do propose in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311720/where-to-tweak-an-eclipse-to-change-the-default-settings-used-when-creating-a-new/1311770#1311770 ;)

Comment: yeah I saw that, that is a nasty hack, no +1 for you

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a extension to handle files with different endings ".xyz"

You have to define an editor which can open this file and you have to define a builder which can build this file.

The editor implementation for files which includes java source code can be, that you extend from the eclipse java editor and implement the extension point "org.eclipse.ui.editors".Add the file extension to the editor extension preference entry "extensions".

When you than open the specific file, the editor is used you have added.
I dont now if you can add a additional extension to an editor which is defined in an eclipse plugin.  I think you have to do it by your own.

When you want to build the specific file as it usual is in eclipse, you have to implement a new builder, using "org.eclipse.core.resource.builders".
I do not have an example but the key word is "nature" (org.eclipse.core.resources.natures).
As far as i now you can add this builders to project you defined. I am not sure if you can add these builders to existing projects like a "Java plugin project".

---

When you just want to add a editor to a file extension you can do this in the preference page

"General" - "Editors" - "File Associations"