# Where to tweak an Eclipse to change the default settings used when creating a new Workspace?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

We use Eclipse with projects in CVS.  It has proven to be the simplest to create a new workspace when having to deal with another branch or application, and then use Team -> Import project set to get all the needed projects from CVS.

Unfortunately, I then have to do the following each and every time:

- Change text font to Consolas 11 pt
- Disable spell checking in text editors
- Run everything in the background

plus some more of the same.

I'd like to change the standard values once and for all in the Eclipse distribution files after having unzipped the distribution (Windows).  Where are these defaults located inside Eclipse?

---

EDIT:  For now we just have a preference file which must be read in.  An extra step, but works...

---

EDIT 2014: I've ended up creating a workspace with the settings I want, and then creating a new copy everytime I need a new one.  Also handles Maven Central information etc.  Accepted the oldest answer saying essentially this.

Comment: Just added a "solution" which does modifies CVS default options

Comment: After switching to git it turned out that Eclipse m2e was not fond of Maven modules appearing and disappearing when switching branches.  This might have improved.  IntelliJ did this much better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created a clean workspace with all settings i want to have. This workspace i have copied into a save folder i will never delete ;)

When i want to create a workspace for a new project, i copy the confugured workspace and thats it.

I have than configured the svn repository path, code format (you also can import preferences in eclipse for this), view configuration and so on.

Answer (score 16):

You can export your settings from a workspace and import them into any other (this basically does what VonC's answer says, but with some measure of error checking).

To do so, in the source workspace select **File**->**Export...**->**General**->**Preferences**, then select **Export All** and enter a file to export to, then **Finish**.

You can then import the preferences into any workspace by doing **File**->**Import...**->**General**->**Preferences**, browse to the preferences file and hitting **Finish**.

Comment: does this also import fonts,spell check preferences etc?

Comment: It will export the references to those files, so if you had a user dictionary in c:\user.dict, you'll see an entry like this: /instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/spelling_user_dictionary=c\:\\user.dict

Comment: Sometimes to get new developer/machine set up quickly we just copy workspace directory from existing installation, but what you said seems to be more proper way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Try checking:

```
<workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings
```

Some `.prefs` files could be interesting to copy from one workspace to the next.
(like `org.eclipse.team.cvs.ui.prefs` which contains any non-default value for CVS settings)

---

> I want to fix the defaults inside Eclipse so the workspace is created with the defaults I want every time.

Hard core solution:

Change the `.options` file within `<eclipse-SDK-3.5-win32>\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.team.cvs.core_3.3.200.I20090430-0408.jar` (that is the name I have for eclipse3.5)
That is the file with the default values, at least for CVS.

Comment: I do not want to fix the created workspace after creation.  I want to fix the defaults inside Eclipse so the workspace is created with the defaults I want every time.  Suggestions?

Comment: @Thorbjørn: I'm not sure if that is possible without digging up the Eclipse source. But you might find the script located at http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/create-new-eclipse-workspace-w to be useful.

Comment: Note to self: this answer was accepted in Jan 18 '10, and unaccepted Jan 20 '14. 4 years later! That must be some kind of record :)

Comment: @VonC You probably got a badge for that too :)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Note to self: Thorbjørn's comment was made in Jan 2018, about a comment I made in January 2014. 4 years later! That must be some kind of record :) Wait... inception. Must Go Deeper. And still no badge for all this, by the way...

Comment: Let's revisit this next leap year!

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I do:

1. Start up Eclipse
2. Without importing or starting any projects, edit the workspace and make all the config changes you want
3. Open up the workspace in windows explorer and create a copy of the folder.
4. Then, any time you wish to use it, copy this folder to your new workspace folder location - you may need to create the new workspace folder first (and definitely call it something different.)

This is what I do anyway. Yes, it's very dirty but it does get what I want pretty quickly!

Answer (score 1):

When importing preferences (Rich Seller's approach above), especially those that were created by someone else, make sure you backup your Eclipse environment first.  That's easy, since it's portable - just copy it to a temporary location.

I've totally hosed my Eclipse environment importing preferences in the past, and importing my own preferences, which I exported just prior to importing, did not fix my issues.

Answer (score 1):

Fix the defaults inside Eclipse so the workspace is created with the defaults, If you want every time suggestions, then

Go to eclipse extract path `-eclipse\configuration\.settings` -> Edit `-org.eclipse.ui.ide` ->
Change value to true: `SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG=true`

Similarly in this file you can directly change other default settings.

Comment: this is cool but seems to only work for stuff in the .settings folder, and most of them are in workspace\.metadata\.plugins. any idea how to change those?

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to do that:

```
open <eclipse>\plugins\org.eclipse.cpp.package.cpp_1.4.2.201210131-1456\plugin_customization.ini
```

and add

folding

```
  org.eclipse.cdt.ui/editor_folding_enabled=true
  org.eclipse.cdt.ui/editor_folding_preprocessor_enabled=true
```

then new project will enable folding by default.

---

So

1. You need to know where your prefer locate, in my case, folding is under `org.eclipse.cdt.ui`, you can try on an project then check `<workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings` to find it
2. `"org.eclipse.cpp.package.cpp_1.4.2.201210131-1456"` should be variable depends on what version you use.  whatever it's, you should find `"plugin_customization.ini "`