# Get Eclipse columns to stay as they've been set

Tags: eclipse, settings, multiple-columns

I've customized the perspectives I use often in Eclipse pretty thoroughly. Sometimes, however, I accidentally close a window and I need to reopen it. However, when I do, all the selected columns reset to the defaults.

The easiest way to reproduce this, is in Java mode (or any mode, I suppose):

1. Choose upside-down triangle in the Tasks view
2. Click configure columns
3. Remove a column, such as "Completion".
4. Window -> Save Perspective as... It will say "do you wish to overwrite Java"?

   - Choose yes, because the changes don't actually save anyway
5. Window -> New Window

And you will see, in the new Window, the removed column has returned!

Is there a way to make this change permanent? I tried looking through the files in /.metadata/.plugins/.org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings but as I didn't know what I was looking for, I didn't know what to change. I also tried File->Export->General->Preferences, but the Tasks settings file created there had no mention of columns. [I also tried the advice in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311720/where-to-tweak-an-eclipse-to-change-the-default-settings-used-when-creating-a-ne) but none of it was helpful really. Does this feature exist?

Edit: After getting little response here and on their forums, [I have created an Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=413443)

Comment: Which Eclipse are you using?

Comment: @VonC: I am using Kepler