# How to combine two different editors in a single file?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

In eclipse plugin development,i am trying to combine two different editors (html and Java editors) in a single multipage editor.

Can anyone guide me on this.

Thanks in advance

regards
Mathan

Comment: Just completed my answer in response to your last comment

Answer (score 2):

You can check out the [Multi-page Editor Example](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/samples/org.eclipse.ui.examples.multipageeditor/doc-html/ui_multipageeditor_ex.html), which adds an editor for files with the .mpe extension. It shows how to create an editor that uses multiple pages by defining both an editor and a page contributor that can add entries to an action bar.

Also Eclipse Wiki: ["FAQ How do I make an editor that contains another editor?"](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_make_an_editor_that_contains_another_editor%3F)

Both are based on [Multi-page form editors](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/forms_editors.htm).

---

Regarding the issue of "Compilation unit name must end with .java, or one of the registered java-like extensions", may be this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305558/eclipse-plugin-treat-non-java-extension-file-like-a-java-file/1305699#1305699) can help (i.e. defining a new `<content-type>`)

Comment: Thanks Vonc,

Yes i am using multipage editor for combining these two editors(html and Java editors).
In my application i have mutipage editor file with .mpe extension, which is stored physically in the workspace.
And i have java editor file (placed as a child file in mutipageeditor) with .java extension, this is also stored physically in the workspace.

My concern is, 
How to avoid by keeping .java file as a separated physical file.
If i remove this java file i am getting a runtime error like "Compilation unit name must end with .java, or one of the registered java-like extensions"